# DMatch Class Opencv

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I'm making a application that detects and recognizes an object on Android. With some research on the area I made the application and got some results, like this:
[image]

However, I want to train my image, and I found on **DMatch class** that atributes **trainIdx** and **queryIdx** in the link below:

[OpenCV documentarion](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/features2d/DMatch.html)

Can someone explain how can I use that on my application and the definition of those attributes ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::DMatch` is the class that holds the [results of a matcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html).
Given a bunch of training descriptors and another bunch of query descriptors, `DMatch` tells you what the best match was for each query descriptor.

For each *found* match, `DMatch` will tell you the: query descriptor index, the  train descriptor index, train image index (each image generates multiple training descriptors), and distance between these query and training descriptors.

See [this example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp) for more detailed usage.

Comment: So, this is not use to train images, right ? Do you know how can i train image to have a better results ?

Comment: You train the matcher using `train`. The example code shows how to do it. `DMatch` is just a strict that holds the matching results per query descriptor.

Comment: So the attribute **train** is already training my images ? I really don't understand how we happening. Can someone provide some case detecting and recognize a image trained ?
Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Please take a look at the (C++) example I linked to. You first find/detect the features in each image, then create a descriptor around each feature. You do thi both for the training set and the query set. Then you train a matcher (using the method `train()`) and match the query descriptors to the DB of trained descriptors. The matching results will be held in the `cv::DMatch`  structs.

Comment: Thanks i will check that! Thanks :)